# Java GUI not showing up but there are no errors

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to get this GUI to show up and take user input to perform calculations in a separate class, however when I run the program it runs and says build successful but nothing happens. I think i need to create some type of instance of the class but I have tried putting it in multiple spots and nothing seems to be working . Here is my code:

```
class infoGUI extends JFrame {

  private JButton btnOK  = new JButton("OK");
  private JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

  private JTextField txtCustomerName = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtCustomerNumber = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtCreditLimit = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtPrevBalance = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtCurrentPurchases = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtPayments = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtCreditsReturns = new JTextField();
  private JTextField txtLatefeeds = new JTextField();


  private JLabel lblCustomerName = new JLabel("Name :");
  private JLabel lblCustomerNumber = new JLabel("Number :");
  private JLabel lblCreditLimit = new JLabel("Credit Limit :");
  private JLabel lblPrevbalance = new JLabel("Previous Balance :");
  private JLabel lblCurrentPurchases = new JLabel("Current Purchases :");
  private JLabel lblPayments = new JLabel("Payments :");
  private JLabel lblCreditsReturns = new JLabel("Credits/Returns :");
  private JLabel lblLateFees = new JLabel("Late Fees :");

  public infoGUI(){
    this.name = null;
    setTitle("Credit Wizard");
    setSize(300,375);
    setLayout(null);    
    setResizable(false);


    initComponent();
    initEvent();

  }
  private void initComponent(){
    btnOK.setBounds(20,300, 80,25);
    btnCancel.setBounds(110,300, 80,25);

    txtCustomerName.setBounds(100,10,100,20);
    txtCustomerNumber.setBounds(100,35,100,20);
    txtCreditLimit.setBounds(100,65,100,20);
    txtPrevBalance.setBounds(130,95,100,20);
    txtCurrentPurchases.setBounds(135,125,100,20);
    txtPayments.setBounds(100,155,100,20);
    txtCreditsReturns.setBounds(120,185,100,20);
    txtLatefeeds.setBounds(100,215,100,20);


    lblCustomerName.setBounds(20,10,100,20);
    lblCustomerNumber.setBounds(20,35,100,20);
    lblCreditLimit.setBounds(20,65,100,20);
    lblPrevbalance.setBounds(20,95,120,20);
    lblCurrentPurchases.setBounds(20,125,125,20);
    lblPayments.setBounds(20,155,100,20);
    lblCreditsReturns.setBounds(20,185,120,20);
    lblLateFees.setBounds(20,215,100,20);

    add(btnOK);
    add(btnCancel);

    add(lblCustomerName);
    add(lblCustomerNumber);
    add(lblCreditLimit);
    add(lblPrevbalance);
    add(lblCurrentPurchases);
    add(lblPayments);
    add(lblCreditsReturns);
    add(lblLateFees);

    add(txtCustomerName);
    add(txtCustomerNumber);
    add(txtCreditLimit);
    add(txtPrevBalance);
    add(txtCurrentPurchases);
    add(txtPayments);
    add(txtCreditsReturns);
    add(txtLatefeeds);
  }
  private void initEvent(){
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
       System.exit(1);
      }
    });

    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnCancelClick(e);
      }
    });

    btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnOKClick(e);
      }
    });
  }

  private void btnCancelClick(ActionEvent evt){
    System.exit(0);
  } 
  private String name;
  private double custNum;
  private double creditLimit;
  private double prevBalance;
  private double currentPurchases;
  private double payments;
  private double creditsReturns;
  private double lateFees;
  private void btnOKClick(ActionEvent evt){

    try{
      String custName = (txtCustomerName.getText());
      setName(custName);
      custNum = Double.parseDouble(txtCustomerNumber.getText());
      setCustNum(custNum);
      creditLimit = Double.parseDouble(txtCreditLimit.getText());
      setCreditLimit(creditLimit);
      prevBalance = Double.parseDouble(txtPrevBalance.getText());
      setPrevBalance(prevBalance);
      currentPurchases = Double.parseDouble(txtPrevBalance.getText());
      setCurrentPurchases(currentPurchases);
      payments = Double.parseDouble(txtPayments.getText());
      setPayments(payments);
      creditsReturns = Double.parseDouble(txtCreditsReturns.getText());
      setCreditsReturns(creditsReturns);
      setLateFees(lateFees);
      System.exit(0);      
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
          e.toString(),
          "Error", 
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    }

   public void setName(String newName){  
    name = newName;

    }
   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }
   public void setCustNum(double newCustNum){  
    custNum = newCustNum;
   }
   public double getCustNum(){
       return custNum;
   }
   public void setCreditLimit(double newCreditLimit){  
    creditLimit = newCreditLimit;
    }
   public double getCreditLimit(){
       return creditLimit;
   }
   public void setPrevBalance(double newPrevBalance){  
    prevBalance = newPrevBalance;
    } 
   public double getPrevBalance(){
       return prevBalance;
   }
   public void setCurrentPurchases(double newCurrentPurchases){  
    currentPurchases = newCurrentPurchases;
    }
   public double getCurrentPurchases(){
       return currentPurchases;
   }
   public void setPayments(double newPayments){  
   payments = newPayments; 
    }
   public double getPayments(){
       return payments;
   }
   public void setCreditsReturns(double newCreditsReturns){
    creditsReturns = newCreditsReturns;
   }
    public double getCreditsReturns(){
       return creditsReturns;
   }
   public void setLateFees(double newLateFees){
    lateFees = newLateFees;
    }
   public double getLateFees(){
       return lateFees;
   }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is Swing is it not? Where is your `setVisible(true)`? Also, where is your `main`?

Comment: try to use `setVisible(true)` after initializing the component.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a new GUI in a `main` method. Also, call `setVisible(true)` at the end of your JFrame's constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   new infoGUI(); // creates a new GUI 
}
```

And:

```
  public infoGUI(){
    super(); 
    this.name = null;
    setTitle("Credit Wizard");
    setSize(300,375);
    setLayout(null);    
    setResizable(false);


    initComponent();
    initEvent();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // good idea to put this in
    setVisible(true);
  }
```

Comment: tried this out still not working, is there a specific place the main method should be? also says the new instance is ignored.

Comment: The main method should be in the class which you are running as this method is executed to run the application.  Where does it say the new instance is ignored?

Comment: PS I added the super()  call to the constructor of the infoGUI

Comment: Seems to be working now but it still does have the new instance is ignored warning in the main class

Comment: The warning is possibly because of the instance not being used or assigned to anything. Does it go away if you say InfoGUI gui = new infoGUI() ?